# image sprite - how to select correct area and then place in desired location

Tags: css, positioning, background-image, css-sprites

I've been fiddling with an image sprite to be used in a  background.

I need to select two parts of an image and then place them in different locations in the body background, one in the bottom left and one in the top right.

Lets say I have an image that is a rectangle - 1700px wide and 1100px tall. This is my image sprite.

I need to select a rectangle shaped area from the image sprite that is 600px wide and 400px tall from the top right of the sprite. I need to place this part in the top right of the body element as a background.

I then need to select the bottom left most part of the image sprite that is also 600px wide and 400px tall. I need to place this part in the bottom right of the body as a background image.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can only set one background image per element, so you would have to add pseudo elements (:after/:before)

```
#area {
    position: relative; /*by relatively positioning the element it acts as the reference point when absolutely positioning the pseudo-elements*/
    z-index:1; /*positive z-index will allow for the correct z-axis positioning of the pseudo-elements*/
    /*you could set any background you want, your 2 background images will be in :before and :after*/
}
#area:before,#area:after {
    position: absolute; /*we want to position them*/
    z-index: -1; /*_back_ground-images... so they are behind #area*/
}
#area:before {
    /*set width, height, the 1st background-image, ... here*/
}
#area:after {
    /*set width, height, the 2nd background-image, ... here*/
}
```

you may have to add display:block and content:" " to your pseudo elements, so they don't get omited

EDIT: I assume you know the basics of CSS background-sprites, pretty much everything else has now been done for you ;)